# Video overlay on Windows (using C#?)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, video-processing

I am working on a video processing library in C# and would like to display videos on Windows XP up. For this purpose, I currently use a custom double-buffered `UserControl` with overridden `OnPaint` that uses `Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled`. This works okay, but is not ideal.

Therefore I would like to implement a video display using [hardware overlay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_overlay), like so many other video players.

How do I do this? In C#? Or C/C++?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using OpenGL via the excellent [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com) library which works on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X. In effect, I copy frames into a texture which is then mapped onto a quad that fills out the entire viewport. Works like an ace.

Thanks for all your suggestions,

Christian.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using WPF and the [MediaElement Class?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but I'm currently not using WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using DirectShow? [Here's an example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directshowmediaplayer.aspx).

Comment: I looked into this and it would be quite clumsy to use, as Microsoft does not officially support DirectShow use in a managed environment.